# How to use WebApi ActionFilter Attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here I wrote simple Actioon Filter As

```
 public class ActionFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Action Method {0} executing at {1}",actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()), "Web API Logs");
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Action Method {0} executed at {1}",actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName,  DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));
        }
```

**In WebApi**

```
[ActionFilter]
        public IHttpActionResult GetData()
        {
        }
```

Here it working Before and after But im not Understanding Why this Filter Came into Picture

Comment: Check out [ASP.NET Web API Pipe line](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) or [Google Web API Pipeline](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+api+pipeline)

Comment: Checkout [ASP.NET Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) and they're designed to be executed before and after the Action is executed. For example, in case of Authorize you can invalidate the request in Before handler if it is not authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action Filters are basically used to execute some logic before and after of an Action execution.

Lets think about two scenerios:

1. If you have requirement to check if a user can access a particular **Action**, you can simply write the code to validate it in **OnActionExecuting()** function of the code.
2. Again if you want to modify th response of want to perform any activity after an Action is executed, you can use **OnActionExecuted** function filter for that.

For more information about Filters you can check following link:
[Action Filters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_action_filters.htm)